# Are there getattr, callable and other metaprogramming functions in java?

Tags: java, metaprogramming, getattr

I'm looking for some metaprogramming functions in Java analogous to Python's getattr, hasattr, callable etc. If not, is there any good external library for this?

Comment: Java has Reflection, but it is nowhere as usable as Python's support for metaprogramming. Languages like Java and C# (especially the former, but also the latter to a lesser extent) were designed under the premise that programmers should not try to be too "clever".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eduardo commented, you can use reflection.  Here's Sun's (Oracle, now) article about it:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

That should get you heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Also the JavaBean spec sort of dabbles in this area.

see java.beans.BeanInfo

Also there are libraries such as commons-beanutils that is built on reflection that tries to be more meta-handling-like.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the best "libraries" for metaprogramming take the form of alternative languages that run on the JVM; for example, the Groovy language is a slightly simplified Java with better metaprogramming support (among other features).

Answer (score 0):

Besides reflection, you may be interested in AOP (e.g., via [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/)) which allows pre- and/or post-processing of method calls, transformations, interceptions, etc. of various Java execution sequences.

There's no way to intercept calls to methods that don't exist, because such code cannot be compiled.